# How do I permanently dismiss the ..."Powered by Data Catalogue" pop-up in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently (last month or two) I've been noticing a popup that keeps showing up when I open BigQuery. It says:

> Try search and autocomplete powered by Data Catalogue

When I hit "Dismiss" on this pop-up it goes away for a while but as soon as I come back to the BQ query editor it just comes back again. It's infuriating!

Does anyone know how to get rid of this advertising permanently without enabling it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been reported on [issuetracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170626505) platform, which says that:

> The Prompt will not be visible by default once BigQuery UI's 'V2 Beta'
> version is launched in November.

I will recommend you to [subscribing the issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) by starring it. When you star an issue, you receive email notifications about any upcoming chnages. Additionally, keep track of the latest BigQuery releases [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).